# Get users in query and limit user output to five in random order

Tags: wp-user-query

In the `footer.php` I show all the authors of my blog with the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$wp_user_query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 
    'wp_usermeta.meta_value', $wp_user_query->query_orderby );

// Get the results
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
```

Is it possible to limit the output to 5 random users? Like `posts_per_page => 3` and `orderby => rand`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes possible, just tell WordPress to use `RAND()` SQL sorting when passing `rand` in [`orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) parameter:

```
add_action( "pre_user_query", function( $query ) {
    if( "rand" == $query->query_vars["orderby"] ) {
        $query->query_orderby = str_replace( "user_login", "RAND()", $query->query_orderby );
    }
});
```

Now you can use:

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'number'  => 3 // limit
));

print_r( $users );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your solution works perfect thank you! I made a mistake in my post. The output should always be 5 random users, not limited to 5.

Comment: Thanks but isn't it always outputting 5 random users?

Comment: No the output is something between 1 and 5 users

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_random_authors($number) {

$users = wp_list_authors( array(
'orderby' => 'rand',
'number'  => $number // limit
));

return $users;

}

print_r(get_random_authors(3));
```